# File.list returning limited File resource data

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the google api v2 to retrieve all files in my google drive, I successfully get file list but there's no detail like size, creation date...
This is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('XXX');
client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

//$client->setAccessType('offline');
//$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');


$creds = @file_get_contents("ggcreds");

$client->setAccessToken($creds);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (!$service)
    exit();

$pageToken = NULL;

do
{
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;

    $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
    $pageToken=$files->nextPageToken;

    $files = $files->files;

    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)
    {
        if (!isset($files[$i]))
            break;

        print_r($files[$i]);
    }
}
while($pageToken);
```

So I tried to get all file details for one file:

```
$service->files->get($id)
```

But I get that:

```
Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => spaces
    [appProperties] => 
    [capabilitiesType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities
    [capabilitiesDataType:protected] => 
    [contentHintsType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints
    [contentHintsDataType:protected] => 
    [createdTime] => 
    [description] => 
    [explicitlyTrashed] => 
    [fileExtension] => 
    [folderColorRgb] => 
    [fullFileExtension] => 
    [hasAugmentedPermissions] => 
    [hasThumbnail] => 
    [headRevisionId] => 
    [iconLink] => 
    [id] => 1dDXhxWf6kN-keNmi5-009o_oeQ5xWXXXXX
    [imageMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata
    [imageMediaMetadataDataType:protected] => 
    [isAppAuthorized] => 
    [kind] => drive#file
    [lastModifyingUserType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [lastModifyingUserDataType:protected] => 
    [md5Checksum] => 
    [mimeType] => image/jpeg
    [modifiedByMe] => 
    [modifiedByMeTime] => 
    [modifiedTime] => 
    [name] => IMG_20180110_165918.jpg
    [originalFilename] => 
    [ownedByMe] => 
    [ownersType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [ownersDataType:protected] => array
    [parents] => 
    [permissionsType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_Permission
    [permissionsDataType:protected] => array
    [properties] => 
    [quotaBytesUsed] => 
    [shared] => 
    [sharedWithMeTime] => 
    [sharingUserType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [sharingUserDataType:protected] => 
    [size] => 
    [spaces] => 
    [starred] => 
    [teamDriveId] => 
    [thumbnailLink] => 
    [thumbnailVersion] => 
    [trashed] => 
    [trashedTime] => 
    [trashingUserType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
    [trashingUserDataType:protected] => 
    [version] => 
    [videoMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata
    [videoMediaMetadataDataType:protected] => 
    [viewedByMe] => 
    [viewedByMeTime] => 
    [viewersCanCopyContent] => 
    [webContentLink] => 
    [webViewLink] => 
    [writersCanShare] => 
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I tried to add more scopes with no luck and the scope "drive" is supposed to include all (no?).

Also I tried in the google api explorer with the first file id I got and it gives all details with just the drive scope so I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think you are using Google Drive v3 not v2 i can see this by your response.  File resource in v2 had title in v3 its name.

By default Drive v3 does not return all the values of all the fields google wants you to use the fields parameter to only return the data you want.  personally i like to see everything so just use *

I think you need to try and add the fields parameter.  This should return all of the information.

```
$parameters['fields'] = '*';
```

Comment: OK, it works however I think I'm using v2 , how can I check

Comment: file resource name is v3